# How to remove a specific json key-value pair within a json based column in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, json, sql-update

I am trying to update a column in MySQL, where it contains a json encoded value with multiple key-value pairs, but cannot write the exact query. Can anyone help?

For example:

tableA:

| id | response |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"event_id":"11111","contact":{"contact_id":"as2344","answers": [{"answer_id":"2223e"}],"tags":"cadd76","question_id":"67888"} |

From the above row, I am trying to remove "answers" and "tags" from the key "contact", so that the result after the update query will be like below:

```
{"event_id":"11111","contact":{"contact_id":"as2344","question_id":"67888"}
```

I cannot find any method as to how to update that column. So please anyone can help?

Comment: Update tableA set response = 'new string' where id = 1 ?

And 'new string' is the new thing you want to go into that response field.  Is this what you need?  Let me know so i can type up a proper answer?

Comment: Then for the new string part you can perhaps idk use a regex to scrub out those fields.  Or maybe even a replace but most likely you need a pattern so Regex will be the best but more difficult to configure than just some Replace lines.

Comment: Update tableA set response = 'new string' where id = 1 ? And 'new string' is the new thing you want to go into that response field. Is this what you need? ==> Yes I need this only

Comment: UPDATE tableA SET response = '{"event_id":"11111","contact":{"contact_id":"as2344","question_id":"67888"}' WHERE id = 1

Comment: If that is what you are after this above one should do it short of the wrapping the string in the ' ' single quotes but afaik it should work.  BUT .. because your string ALSO has ' in it .. it might terminate early and not paste the whole thing if you aren't careful.   This is one of the main reasons using JSON in MYSQL is a bad idea, and should be stored in MongoDB to avoid the termination character issues.

Comment: If you can confirm it worked, I will type up a proper response, just let me know.  ty.

Comment: No, I am actually running a cron job to remove the json key as mentioned above, and then update that row. In, PHP, I can unset that json key and then update that row. But I need to do it in MySQL.

Comment: Well the UPDATE statement I provided on about the 4th response is the statement you would pass to the server to do it.  As far as how to format that into cron?  I have no idea .. but if you want an even easier way to do it, my not use MySQL Workbench and just right click and be done?

Comment: Your JSON is missing a closing curly brace.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to remove "answers" and "tags" from the key "contact"

In MySQL, you can use [`JSON_REMOVE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-remove) for this, since version 5.7:

```
select json_remove(response, '$.contact.answers', '$.contact.tags') new_response
from t
```

Or if you wanted an `update` statement:

```
update t
set response = json_remove(response, '$.contact.answers', '$.contact.tags')
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0qVuUBch)**

Note that modifying stored JSON is somehow a red-flag that indicates a data model problem; in many cases, it is much easier to properly model your relationships into database tables, and then use standard DML capabilities.